# jquery show hide multiple divs on click - want hide the trigger clicked link after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code to show/hide multiple divs: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7pxpk)

HTML

```
<ul class="fade_text">
    <li><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('astro-1'); return false;" class="toggle"><h4>Was ist ein Teleskop?</h4></a>

        <div id="astro-1" class="showHideDiv">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('astro-2'); return false;" class="toggle"><h4>Lichtsammelvermögen</h4></a>

        <div id="astro-2" class="showHideDiv">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('astro-3'); return false;" class="toggle"><h4>Grenzgröße (der schwächsten erkennbaren Sterne)</h4></a>

        <div id="astro-3" class="showHideDiv">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('astro-4'); return false;" class="toggle"><h4>Auflösung(svermögen)</h4></a>

        <div id="astro-4" class="showHideDiv">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick="showdiv('astro-5'); return false;" class="toggle"><h4>Vergrößerung</h4></a>

        <div id="astro-5" class="showHideDiv">
           Some Content
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showHideDivs() {
        $('.showHideDiv').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prevAll('a.toggle:first').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }

    $('a.toggle').click(function () {
        var addExpanded = !$(this).hasClass('expanded');
        $('a.toggle').removeClass('expanded');
        if (addExpanded) {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
        showHideDivs();
    });

    showHideDivs();
});
```

Everything is working fine. 
My question: I want to hide the link f.e. "Lichtsammelvermögen" after the link is clicked and the text container is shown.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add the code into your question.

Comment: He's refering to the code in the Fiddle.

Comment: @Wayne Ah, I missed the fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a `hide()` call

```
    $(this).hide();
```

if you want to re-show it when clicking another header you can do this too:

```
    $('a').show();
    $(this).hide();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7pXpK/11/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... When you make changes that work, you click update and copy that url.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7pXpK/10/

Write `$(this).hide()` when `addExpanded` is false.

```
    $('a.toggle').click(function () {
        var addExpanded = !$(this).hasClass('expanded');

        if (addExpanded) {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        } else {
            $('a.toggle').removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).hide();
        }
        showHideDivs();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot too. Great !! 2 answers within 3 minutes, Awesome